# Is there a zip-like function that pads to longest length?

Tags: python, list, zip

Is there a built-in function that works like [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) but that will pad the results so that the length of the resultant list is the length of the *longest* input rather than the *shortest* input?

```
>>> a = ['a1']
>>> b = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
>>> c = ['c1', 'c2']

>>> zip(a, b, c)
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1')]

>>> What command goes here?
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), (None, 'b2', 'c2'), (None, 'b3', None)]
```

Answer (score 389, accepted):

In Python 3 you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(a, b, c))
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), (None, 'b2', 'c2'), (None, 'b3', None)]
```

You can pad with a different value than `None` by using the `fillvalue` parameter:

```
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(a, b, c, fillvalue='foo'))
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('foo', 'b2', 'c2'), ('foo', 'b3', 'foo')]
```

With Python 2 you can either use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (Python 2.6+), or you can use `map` with `None`. It is a little known [feature of `map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) (but `map` changed in Python 3.x, so this only works in Python 2.x).

```
>>> map(None, a, b, c)
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), (None, 'b2', 'c2'), (None, 'b3', None)]
```

Comment: Do we not have a non itertools Python 3 solution?

Comment: @PascalvKooten it is not required. `itertools` is a builtin C module anyway.

Answer (score 92):

For Python 2.6x use `itertools` module's [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

For Python 3 use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead (no leading `i`).

```
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(a, b, c))
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), (None, 'b2', 'c2'), (None, 'b3', None)]
```

Comment: In case you want to make your code both python 2 and python 3 compatible, you can use `six.moves.zip_longest` instead.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you're working with iterables that *might* be different lengths but *shouldn't* be, it's recommended to pass `strict=True` to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (supported since Python 3.10).

To quote the documentation:

> `zip()` is often used in cases where the iterables are assumed to be of
> equal length. In such cases, it’s recommended to use the `strict=True`
> option. Its output is the same as regular `zip()`:
>
> ```
> >>> list(zip(('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3), strict=True))
> [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
> ```
>
> Unlike the default behavior, it checks that the
> lengths of iterables are identical, raising a `ValueError` if they
> aren’t:
>
> ```
> >>> list(zip(range(3), ['fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum'], strict=True))
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> ValueError: zip() argument 2 is longer than argument 1
> ```
>
> Without the `strict=True` argument, any bug
> that results in iterables of different lengths will be silenced,
> possibly manifesting as a hard-to-find bug in another part of the
> program.

Answer (score 9):

non itertools Python 3 solution:

```
def zip_longest(*lists):
    def g(l):
        for item in l:
            yield item
        while True:
            yield None
    gens = [g(l) for l in lists]    
    for _ in range(max(map(len, lists))):
        yield tuple(next(g) for g in gens)
```

Comment: this works in micropython, thanks @dansalmo !

Comment: Let me know if anyone has a solution like this that works with not just lists, but generators or non-indexable iterables.

Answer (score 4):

non itertools My Python 2 solution:

```
if len(list1) < len(list2):
    list1.extend([None] * (len(list2) - len(list1)))
else:
    list2.extend([None] * (len(list1) - len(list2)))
```

Comment: Very nice. It made me think of a similar approach: `short, long = (xs, ys) if len(xs) < len(ys) else (ys, xs); short.extend([None] * (len(long) - len(short)))`, where `xs` and `ys` are two lists of not necessarily the same length.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers already given, the following works for any iterable and does not use `itertools`, answering @ProdIssue's question:

```
def zip_longest(*iterables, default_value):
    iterators = tuple(iter(i) for i in iterables)
    sentinel = object()
    while True:
        new = tuple(next(i, sentinel) for i in iterators)
        if all(n is sentinel for n in new):
            return
        yield tuple(default_value if n is sentinel else n for n in new)
```

The use of `sentinel` is needed so an iterator yielding `default_value` will not be erroneously be identified as empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just use iterators, nothing fancy.

```
def zip_longest(*iterables):
    items = 0
    for iterable in iterables:
        items = max(items, len(iterable))

    iters = [iter(iterable) for iterable in iterables]
    while items:
        yield (*[next(i, None) for i in iters],)
        items -= 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Im using a 2d array but the concept is the similar using python 2.x:

```
if len(set([len(p) for p in printer])) > 1:
    printer = [column+['']*(max([len(p) for p in printer])-len(column)) for column in printer]
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this code works. Or why it is the right answer