# Calling none in maps in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, map-function

I am doing the following in Python2.7:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [2,1,3,4]
>>> c = [3,4]
>>> map(None, a, b, c)
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 4), (3, 3, None), (4, 4, None), (5, None, None)]
```

I am trying to do something similar in Python3

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [2,1,3,4]
>>> c = [3,4]
>>> map(None, a, b, c)
<map object at 0xb72289ec>
>>> for i,j,k in map(None, a, b, c):
...  print (i,j,k)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How do I replicate the Python2 results in Python3?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015521/python-3-vs-python-2-map-behavior) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`itertools.zip_longest()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for i, j, k in zip_longest(a, b, c):
```

This zips together the three lists, padding out with the `fillvalue` keyword value (defaulting to `None`).