# python - Nested list in dict to csv files

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I tried to create a csv file from two json files.

First json file :

```
{ "attributes": [
        {
            "code": "ean",
            "description": "the ean",
            "example": null,
            "hierarchy_code": null,
            "label": "ean",
            "required": true,
            "type": "TEXT",
            "type_parameter": null,
            "values": null,
            "values_list": "some value"
        },
        ...
```

Second json file :

```
{
    "code": "the code",
    "label": "shoes",
    "values": [
        {
            "code": "COL_100",
            "label": "white"
        },
        {
            "code": "COL_101",
            "label": "blue"
        },
        ...
```

I need to get the value from the key "values_list" in the first json.
With that key I can get a list from second json (which return a random number of values) and take the "label" key value.

What I’ve found is to make two loop like these :

```
for att in first_json['attributes']:
    csv_dict[att['values_list']] = []
    for val in second_json['values']:
        csv_dict[att['values_list']].append(val['label'])
```

Which creates a dictionary like these:

```
{'label1': [val1, val2, val3], 
'label2': [otherval1, otherval2, ...], 
...}
```

My question :

With my "csv_dict" dictionary, how can I create a csv structured like this:

```
label1 | label2    | ... | labeln
val1   | otherval1 | ... | valn
val2   | otherval2 | ... |
val3   | ...       | ... |
```

My actual dictionary not seems to fit with the usual use of csv.Dictwriter() method.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

I try to use the zip function like this :

```
for elem in zip(*labels.values()):
    data.append(";".join([otherelm for otherelem in elem]))
```

In hope to create an csv file manually but my attempt failed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you be more specific how your final result should look like? With `dict[att['values_list']]` you are overwriting the value for the same key (`att['values_list']`) multiple times, is this intentionally? And don't use `dict` as a variable name, since it's the name of the dictionary class in Python.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "a csv like this: label1 label2 val1 otherval1 val2 otherval2 val3". Please provide more information.

Comment: I update the my explanations. I hope it'll be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your `csv_dict`, you can do something like

```
import csv
import itertools

csv_dict = {'label1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
            'label2': ['otherval1', 'otherval2'],
            'label3': ['yetanotherval1']}
keys = csv_dict.keys()
csvrows = itertools.izip_longest(*[csv_dict[k] for k in keys], fillvalue='dummy')

with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                            quotechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvwriter.writerow(keys)
    for row in csvrows:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Resulting `out.csv`:

```
label1;label2;label3
val1;otherval1;yetanotherval1
val2;otherval2;dummy
val3;dummy;dummy
```

With the following remarks:

- When you are `zip`ping the dictionary's values, you should specify the 
  order of the keys
- What do you want to do if the columns differ in length (in your example, there are `val1` to `val3`, but only two `otherval`s)? Maybe something like [padding all lists to fit the longest list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/python-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length)?

Comment: In my explanation I write some "..." to simulate an infinite number of values. In fact the length in nested list may differ.

Comment: See updated answer. And I think that you don't actually mean "infinite" but rather "unknown" :)

Comment: "When you are zipping the dictionary's values, you should specify the order of the keys" I can't predict how many keys my dictionary will have, so I thought to use the wild card which can provide a dynamic assignment. But I didn't work with my code.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. "Didn't work for me" doesn't help, always state what you did, what you got and what you expected!

Comment: The data i used, contained unicode string, so the previous code returned an empty list. But now with this version it's works. I have managed the unicode conversion with the csv library. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I see that you updated your question, so it gives a whole other meaning. Try this:

```
import csv

labels =  {
    'label1': ["val1", "val2", "val3"],
    'label2': ["otherval1", "otherval2", "otherval3"]
}

keys = [k for k in labels]

with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
    w.writeheader()
    for group in zip(*labels.values()):
        temp = {}
        for i in group:
            temp[keys[group.index(i)]] = i
        w.writerow(temp)
```

Try this, it should work for any size of the json object

Comment: It was a good idea, same I wanted, but the loop with "*labels.value()" return an empty list.