# Transpose nested generators

Tags: python

Is there a clear way to iterate over items for each generator in a list? I believe the simplest way to show the essence of the question is o proved an expample. Here it is

### 0. Assume we have an function returning generator:

```
def gen_fun(hint):
    for i in range(1,10):
        yield "%s %i" % (hint, i)
```

### 1. Clear solution with straight iteration order:

```
hints = ["a", "b", "c"]
for hint in hints:
    for  txt in gen_fun(hint):
        print(txt)
```

This prints

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
...
b 1
b 2
b 3
...
```

### 2. Cumbersome solution with inverted iterating order

```
hints = ["a", "b", "c"]
generators = list(map(gen_fun, hints))
any = True
while any:
    any = False
    for g in generators:
        try:
            print(next(g))
            any = True
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

This prints

```
a 1
b 1
c 1
a 2
b 2
...
```

This works as expected and does what I want.

### Bonus points:

The same task, but `gen_fun` ranges can differ, i.e

```
def gen_fun(hint):
    if hint == 'a':
        m = 5
    else:
        m = 10
    for i in range(1,m):
        yield "%s %i" % (hint, i)
```

The correct output for this case is:

```
a 1
b 1
c 1
a 2
b 2
c 2
a 3
b 3
c 3
a 4
b 4
c 4
b 5
c 5
b 6
c 6
b 7
c 7
b 8
c 8
b 9
c 9
```

The querstion:

#### Is there a way to implement *case 2* cleaner?

Comment: why do you call list on map? In python2 it is a list, and in python3 it's still iterable

Comment: @en_Knight, in python3 you can only follow it once, but I have to follow it repeatedly. I tried without list first and it produced sort of unexpected results. Try it!

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. And I see what you mean by inverse order, yurib's answer looks good

Comment: @en_Knight, If you have a better definition of what I meant by inverted order, you are welcome :)

Comment: I don't see *any* "inversion" in any iteration order. What are you talking about?  To me inversion == `reversed` or something like that.

Comment: @Bakuriu If he's asking for a better implementation of case 2, it is clear that the expected output is obtained by running the code.

Comment: @eguaio There's no "inversion" of any kind there. I suggest the Op edit his question removing references to things that can only confuse readers. Also, I don't see why we should be forced to run the code to obtain the expected output... he could copy & paste the output for the example he provided, making things clearer even to people who don't have a python installation (e.g. people on mobile).

Comment: @ If you have a better definition of what I meant by inverted order, you are welcome.

Comment: I agree that it's clear from running the code what you mean, but it should probably be clear from the question too. How about "iterate over items for each generator in a list; traverse generator-first not element-first" It's like a depth-wise vs. a breadth-wise search. I also agree that it would be helpful had you put what the output was in each case, not that it's too difficult to run

Comment: Ok, I though of math term `Transpose`. It can be applied here: `Transpose nested generators` may be? I refuse to accept that you can mentally understand what `iterating over items for each generator in a list` is

Comment: @en_Knight, for the auestion body your definition is ok I believe but I don't like it in a title :(

Comment: Fair enough, I think the question is much clearer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you can use `zip()` to achieve the same thing as that whole `while any` loop:

```
hints = ["a", "b", "c"]
generators = list(map(gen_fun, hints))
for x in zip(*generators):
    for txt in x:
        print(txt)
```

output:

```
a 1
b 1
c 1
a 2
b 2
...
```

**UPDATE:**

If the generators are of different length, zip 'trims' them all to the shortest. you can use [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (as suggested by [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/python-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length)) to achieve the opposite behaviour and continue yielding until the longest generator is exhausted. You'll need to filter out the padded values though:

```
hints = ["a", "b", "c"]
generators = list(map(gen_fun, hints))
for x in zip_longest(*generators):
    for txt in x:
        if txt:
            print(txt)
```

Comment: @en_Knight It's inverse compared to solution 1. i.e. hints are in the nested loop.

Comment: Woh! That doesn't work if gen_fun function differ . Overlooked that, sorry

Comment: See edit. (Though I'm really sorry I overlooked that in the first place)

Comment: It should be `itertools.zip_longest` (without `i`) in python 3, but otherwise that's perfect! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

# Case 1
for tup in product('abc', range(1,4)):
    print('{0} {1}'.format(*tup))

print '---'

# Case 2
from itertools import product
for tup in product(range(1,4), 'abc'):
    print('{1} {0}'.format(*tup))
```

Output:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 2
b 3
c 1
c 2
c 3
---
a 1
b 1
c 1
a 2
b 2
c 2
a 3
b 3
c 3
```

Note that the different between case 1 and 2 are just the order of parameters passed into the `product` function and the print statement.

Comment: well, apparently I'm doing some more complicated task in `gen_fun`, so you cannot just strike it out