# 2 dimensional dictionary with iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I would like to collect the installed packages and their versions of hosts to create a grid. The hosts don't necessarily have the same packages. For example:

[image]

In the first step I would like to simple store, and print these values. 
What data structure should I use?

**I would like to store the data somehow liek this:**

```
for .. 
  # read values
  versions[package][host] = version
```

**I would like to print the values somehow like this:**

```
for packagename in packagenames
  print packagename + ": "
  for host in hosts 
    if versions[host][package] is not None
      print versions[host][package]
    print ";"
  print "\n"
```

But because I don't know how many packages are there, and not all packages are exist in every host, I'm not sure how to do this. I guess I should use dictionary, but I'm don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `defaultdict` would be a good choice. You could fill your dictionary as shown in this example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

versions = defaultdict(dict)

versions["openssl"]["host1"] = "1.0.1e"
versions["openssl"]["host2"] = "1.0.1e"
...
```

By using a `defaultdict`, you can simply store your config using a loop, as you suggested.

```
from collections import defaultdict

versions = defaultdict(dict)
for .. 
    # read values
    versions[package][host] = version
```

Printing the dictionary can be a done like this:

```
for package, hosts in versions.items():
    print package + ": "
    for host, version in hosts:
        print host + ": " version 
    print "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Dict is best for storing these data:

```
     dict_data = {host:packagename for (host,packagename) in map(None, hosts, packagenames)}
```

Try this if this works.

Comment: its actually doing zip but will add None for unequal lists:    http://stackoverflow.com/a/1277311/1965509

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather not use a `defaultdict`, this is how it would have been done before they were available:

```
pack_host = {}
for ...
    # read values
    pack_host.setdefault(package, {})[host] = version
```

the `dictionary.setdefault(key,default)` method is oddly-named. It actually gets the value for the first argument, like if you used `dictionary[key]`, but if that key doesn't exist, it sets it to the default value and returns the value.

To print, you could do:

```
for package_name in pack_host:
    print package_name + ':',
    for host in pack_host[package_name]:
        print host,
    print
```