# How to add numbers in a smaller list into a larger list of python continiously

Tags: python, list, encryption, arraylist, list-comprehension

I'm trying to build a poly-alphabetic cipher but I can't find a way of adding a smaller list into a larger list, I have tried with list comprehensions, but still cannot do it. Please help! I want the smaller list to keep adding the same numbers to the larger list

so lets say I have 2 lists like this:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
z = [i + j for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

the result is the following

```
print(z)
[5,7,9]
```

how can I make it so it is:

```
[5,7,9,8,10,12]
```

meaning it keeps adding the same numbers to the longer list,
thank you for the help

Comment: That's because `zip` function stops on the shortest iterator. Because your first list has 3 elements, it would stop after 3 iterations.

You can find an answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277311/840582

Comment: @Vinny The link you shared does not solve this problem. This question wants to loop back and re-use the values again, that link shows how to pad out default values after the end of the shorter list.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I missed that part of re-iterate values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to loop back through `x` as needed

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> z = [i + j for i, j in zip(itertools.cycle(x), y)]
>>> z
[5, 7, 9, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way, I think: 
`z = [y[i] + x[i % len(x)] for i in range(len(y))]`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
z=[a+b for a,b in zip((x*(int(len(y)/len(x))))[:len(y)],y)]
```

How about this with zip