# web scraping and transferring data into excel using python

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

im able to fully scrap the material i needed the problem is i cant get the data into excel.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlsxwriter

page = requests.get('website that gets mined')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)




items = tree.xpath('//h4[@class="item-title"]/text()')
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="price"]/text()')
description = tree.xpath('//div[@class="description text"]/text()')
print 'items: ', items
print 'Prices: ', prices
print 'description', description
```

everything works fine until this section where i try to get the data into excel
this is the error message:

```
for items,prices,description in (array):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x104735e10>> ignored
```

this is what it was trying to do

```
array = [items,prices,description]
workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
col = 0

for items,prices,description in (array):
    worksheet.write(row, col, items)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, prices)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, description)
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to unpack the returned values to write individually? It looks like the library comes with a `write_row` [method](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_row). Your error is telling you that you have more than 3 values which can't be unpacked into `items,prices,description`

Comment: so using writerow from the csv lib its putting all the data in 1 row. i need it to be going as one column.

Comment: You mean one _row_ right? You don't increment your `row` counter until all 3 values are written, suggesting you want a single row

Comment: This puts all the data into excel but the data is written horizontally with the first item in items in A then second item in B etc

   " with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow([items])
    spamwriter.writerow([prices])
    spamwriter.writerow([description])"

Comment: Then I'm lost on your question because that appears to be exactly what your "this is what it was trying to do" code would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "items,prices,description" all have the same length, you could rewrite the final part of the code in :

```
for item,price,desc in zip(items,prices,description)
    worksheet.write(row, col, item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, price)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, desc)
    row += 1
```

If the lists can have unequal lengths you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/python-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length) for alternatives for the `zip` method, but I would be worried for the data consistency.

Comment: this method works but its not giving me the full list of results it gets to 61 instances and stops there

Comment: Check (print)  the lengths of all the arrays before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inevitably, it will be easier to write to a CSV file, or a Text file, rather than an Excel file.

```
import urllib2

listOfStocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "AMZN"]

urls = []

for company in listOfStocks:
    urls.append('http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=' + company + '&d=6&e=28&f=2015&g=m&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv')

Output_File = open('C:/your_path_here/Data.csv','w')

New_Format_Data = ''

for counter in range(0, len(urls)):

    Original_Data = urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).read()

    if counter == 0:
        New_Format_Data = "Company," + urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).readline()

    rows = Original_Data.splitlines(1)

    for row in range(1, len(rows)):

        New_Format_Data = New_Format_Data + listOfStocks[counter] + ',' + rows[row]

Output_File.write(New_Format_Data)
Output_File.close()
```

OR

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

var_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top")

var_html  = var_file.read()

text_file = open("C:/your_path_here/Text1.txt", "wb")
var_file.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(var_html)
for item in soup.find_all(class_='lister-list'):
    for link in item.find_all('a'):
        #print(link)
        z = str(link)
        text_file.write(z + "\r\n")
text_file.close()
```

As a developer, it's difficult to programmatically manipulate Excel files since the Excel is proprietary. This is especially true for languages other than .NET.  On the other hand, for a developer it's easy to programmatically manipulate CSV since, after all, they are simple text files.