# Separating sublist into multiple list and assigning dynamic list_name

Tags: python

I am trying to split a nested list into multiple lists and assign their name dynamically. Untill now, I tried the code below, but it only works when we have equal length sublists and we give them names manually.

```
sub_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,5],   [2,63,6]]

l1, l2, l3 = map(list, zip(*sub_list))
print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l3)

# Output
[1, 4, 2]
[2, 5, 63]
[3, 5, 6]
```

The approach above will fail when we have unequal length sublists such as (`sub_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5], [2]]`) and it does not give lists dynamic names.

I know it can be done by for loop, but I am not able to make list_name using a loop.

Any help will help me to reach more closure to my work

Comment: What output do you expet for `sub_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5], [2]]`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `zip_longest` from `itertools` as follows:

```
sub_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5], [2]]
from itertools import zip_longest
l1, l2, l3 = map(list, zip_longest(*sub_list))
print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l3)

Output:  
# [1, 4, 2]
# [2, 5, None]
# [3, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first question: If you don't want to give a manual name assing the map() to just one variable:

```
sub_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,5],   [2,63,6]]

rotated = map(list, zip(*sub_list))

for r in rotated:
    print(r)

# Output
# [1, 4, 2]
# [2, 5, 63]
# [3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you want to accomplish, but I suggest you take a look at:

- How to use `itertools.zip_longest()`: [Python: zip-like function that pads to longest length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/python-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length) (You can filter out the `None`s afterwards)
- How to create dynamically named vars (although this is generally not the best thing to do): [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

The following code performs in both of your special cases:

1. There are no errors if some input lists are shorter than others
2. Names are procedurally/dynamically generated

   ```
   def rotate_list_matrix(rows):
       nrows = len(rows)

       col_counts = map(lambda lyst: len(lyst), rows)
       ncols = max(col_counts)

       for ci in range(0, ncols): # column index
           lyst = list()
           list_name = "l" + str(ci + 1)
           globals()[list_name] = lyst
           for ri in range(0, nrows):
               try:
                   lyst.append(rows[ri][ci])
               except:
                   break
       return


   list_mata = [[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]]

   list_matb = [[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5   ],
                [7      ]]

   rotate_list_matrix(list_matb)

   print(l1)
   print(l2)
   print(l3)
   ```