# Sum Values If First Values Match

Tags: python

Is there any way i can compare both lists and sum the second value ONLY if the the first value matches? I queried two tables and gave me the results below but not sure if python has some sort of group function i can use to group the account number(first value) and sum the second values if the first value matches.

```
import psycopg2

def connect():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="test", port=5432, database="test", user="test", 
    password="test123")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return cursor

def allocation(cursor,cashdt, sumbmaster):
    alloclist = []
    print("Allocation: ")
    cursor.execute("""select bill_acct,sum(debit_amount) from test.a where 
    cash_date ='"""
               + cashdt + "'" + "and master_bill='" + sumbmaster +"' group by bill_acct")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
         a = row[0],"{:.2f}".format(row[1])
         alloclist.append(a)
     print(alloclist)

 def statement(cursor, billingdt,sumbmaster):
     statementlist = []
     cursor.execute(
         """
         select bill_account,total_due_amount from test.b where billing_date ='""" 
     + billingdt + "'" + "and master_bill='" + sumbmaster + "'")
     print("Statement:")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
         a = row[0], "{:.2f}".format(row[1])
         statementlist.append(a)
     print(statementlist)

def main():
    connect()
    allocation(connect(),'2020-02-25','123')
    statement(connect(), '2020-2-14', '345')
```

example

```
list 1 =[('123',1),('345', 2)]
list2 = [('123',1),('345', 2)]
```

output

```
('123',2), ('345',4)
```

Comment: are those lists or tuples? Lists usually have [] brackets and tuples have ()

Comment: I don’t understand what the example has to do with the rest of the code above.

Comment: what will happen if `list1 =[('123',1),('345', 2)]` AND `list2 = [('123',1)]`

Comment: what if the first element doesn't match?

Comment: @Moo10000 Sorry they are list. I edited the examples.

Comment: @Marcos Only display matching ones and do the addition of their second value.

Comment: Okay now its a list of tuples (the way it looks]. Do you mean this? [1,2,3,4] and [1,3,4,5]

Comment: Are matches sensitive or insensitive to position? What output do you expect for ``list1 =[('123',1),('345', 2)]; list2 = [('345', 2), ('123',1)]``? What about additional elements, e.g. ``list2 =[('123',1), ('999', 3), ('345', 2)]``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension

```
[(i[0],i[1]+j[1]) for i,j in zip(list1,list2) if i[0]==j[0]]
```

Comment: The thing is that both list are not the same length. Doesn't ZIP iterate simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way i can compare both lists and sum the second value ONLY if the the first value matches?

Yes:

```
if list1[0] == list2[0]:
    result = list1[1] + list2[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, would i have to do a for loop? I see other comments saying to use zip in the loop but that only works if both list are the same length...in this case they are but what if they arent?

Comment: I don’t know exactly what you mean. Anyway, if you want to do something for every item in a list, you can use a `for` loop. And if you want to iterate over two lists in parallel, you could use `zip`.

Comment: what happens if the lists are different lengths?

Comment: It iterates until the shortest list is exhausted.

Comment: Hmm.. i would need it to keep looking for matches between both lists regardless of length.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/python-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length