# Python, How to zip unequal sized list, if one list 's length less than another, than fill None

Tags: python

For example, I want to zip two different sized list:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[1,2,3,4]

# zip the two list will be [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)]
zip(list1, list2)
```

What I want is:

```
[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(None,4)]
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a zip-like function that pads to longest length in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/is-there-a-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want `itertools.zip_longest`

```py
>>> list1=[1,2,3]
>>> list2=[1,2,3,4]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (None, 4)]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is zip_longest in itertools which does that:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> list(zip_longest(range(1,4), range(1,5)))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (None, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[1,2,3,4]

for _ in range(len(list2)-len(list1)): list1.append(None)

print(list(zip(list1, list2)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (None, 4)]
```