# Python iterate list starting from given index in both directions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to iterate over a list `oblist` with objects starting at a given index  `x`. From this index each iteration I would like to get the two neighboring element indices `x-1` and `x+1`. The iteration should not stop when one side reaches the end of the list, but the other side is not exhausted yet and still has elements. A `None` element should be returned in this case for the exhausted side.

I tried a couple ways with

```
for element_indexprev, element_indexnext in zip(range(1,len(oblist)), range(-1,len(oblist), - 1)):
```

but I'm not getting the desired output. Probably also not the best approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/is-there-a-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length-in-python

Comment: Please don't edit-in a solution to the question. If you solved your problem you can post it as an answer (and even accept it). It goes against the idea of this site being a Q&A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with `zip()` but as you discovered it stops at the end of the smallest list.

You want `itertools.zip_longest()`, docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

It zips to the length of the longest list instead of the shortest. By default it will pad with `None` but you can change that with the `fillvalue` arg if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with a simple for bucle y give you and example below

```
oblist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
start_index = 7

for x in range(len(oblist)):
    x= x+1
    if start_index - x < 0:
        i = None
    else:
        i = oblist[start_index - x]
    if start_index + x > len(oblist) - 1:
        j = None
    else:
        j = oblist[start_index + x]
    if j == None and i == None:
        break
    else:
        print(i , j)

Output
6 8
5 9
4 10
3 11
2 12
1 13
0 14
None 15
None 16
```