# Django framework list all products and sum all sales for each

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**Models.py**

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Period(models.Model):
    period = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Product(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    period = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class Sale(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
```

**Views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                entityquery = form.cleaned_data['entity']
                periodquery = form.cleaned_data['period']
                entities = Entity.objects.get(entity=entityquery)
                periods = Period.objects.get(period=periodquery)
                products = Product.objects.filter(entity=entityquery, period=periodquery).values('id', 'period', 'entity', 'sku')
                for sales in products.iterator():
                    sales = Sale.objects.filter(product__sku=product.sku, product__entity=entityquery, product__period=periodquery).aggregate(Sum('price'))
                return sales
            args = {'form': form, 'products': products, 'periods': periods, 'entities': entities, 'sales': sales}
        return render(request, "products_list.html", args)
```

**Expected Result**

So far I am able to list all the SKU items that were sold based on the criteria (Period and Entity). Lets assume SKU 12 has two sales $10 and $30 and SKU 23 has three sales $5, $5 and $6
and I need to show the total sales for each of those products.

**Input**

```
Entity: Company XZY 
Period: November
```

**Output**

```
SKU  Total Sales
12   40.00
23   16.00
```

Comment: Found the solution here :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/is-there-a-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do `group by` and `SUM` using the the django ORM.

[How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

```
from django.db.models import Sum

sales = Sale.objects.filter(product__sku=product.sku, product__entity=entityquery, product__period=periodquery).values(`product`).annotate(total = Sum('price'))
```

Also, in most cases, is very inefficient to loop over a query.
If at all possible, try to use the built-in ORM methods to avoid this.
This is known as a N+1 query problem.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was trying the built-in ORM and was missing .values() before annotate() and could not get it to work and that is why i tried for loop.

Comment: There are many sku this is not working :( product__sku=product.sku

Comment: getting the following error : Cannot use multi-field values as a filter value.

Comment: In this case, can you try filtering using a list of skus?

Comment: filter(product__sku_in=sku_list) ?

Comment: NameError at 
name 'sku_list' is not defined

Comment: the following works : product_sku__in=product.values('sku') however the template issue persists. I still need to figure out how to list SKU and Total same line

Comment: In the values, try changing the product to product__sku?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225914/discussion-between-roni-x-and-michael-lindsay).