# zip(): if item in file_one exist in file_2, do something

Tags: python, list, zip

I'm having trouble explaining my issue to my coworkers so I'm going to try and keep this simple and theoretical here.

I'm using `zip()` to open a for loop containing two files:

```
for data1, data2 in itertools.zip_longest(file_1, file_2):
```

`file_1` contains 958 lines and `file_2` contains 215 lines.
I want to check line by line, if lines 1-958 in `file_1` exists in `file_2`. I'm using [itertools.zip_longest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/is-there-a-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length/1277311#1277311) because of the size difference but the way I understand it if the files are [unequal length](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/) the leftover lines default to `none` or something you designate.

It seams like `zip()` sets up a 1 to 1 relationship between files. like you can check `a1 to a2` `b1 to b2` and so on. I'm looking to check `a1 to a2` `a1 to b2` `a1 to c2` and so on until `a1` either finds a match and satisfies or does not and does a thing moving on to `b1` doing the same and so on for the 958 lines.

This is how I am imagining it working but it does not work the way I need it to. Is there anything to compare lines of text from two seperate files in the way I'm describing?

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import itertools

file_1 = 958 lines of nasty user input address data
file_2 = 215 lines of clean correct street names from the county


for data1, data2 in itertools.zip_longest(file_1, file_2):
    if data1 not in data2:
         data1 = process.extractOne(data1, data2) # Selects and becomes closest match to fix typo
```

Comment: `zip()` is for iterating in parallel. If you want a cross product, use nested loops.

Comment: Also note that files aren't the same as a list of lines. You need to read all the lines in file1 and check to see if each one it's in each of those from file2 — so again, `zip()` is not the tool needed to do that.